# Why local variable of type "ostringstream" is getting error messages for things that should be valid

Tags: c++, iostream, ostringstream, sstream

Here is my code:

```
% cat ch.cpp
using namespace std;
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

typedef const char* cstring;

class GameCharacter
{
    private:
        string desc;
        string name;
        string chid;
    public:
        GameCharacter(cstring nm, cstring id) :
            chid(id), name(nm)
            {
            }

        void setCharDesc(const char* d) { desc = d; }

        string toString(void);
        virtual void toString(ostream &strm);

};

string GameCharacter::toString(void)
{
    ostringstream buf();
    buf << "character: ID: " << chid << "name: " << name;
    return buf.str();
}
```

===============================================================

And here is the result of compiling:

```
% gcc ch.cpp
ch.cpp: In member function ‘std::string GameCharacter::toString()’:
ch.cpp:30:12: error: invalid operands of types ‘std::ostringstream() {aka std::basic_ostringstream<char>()}’ and ‘const char [16]’ to binary ‘operator<<’
     buf << "character: ID: " << chid << "name: " << name;
            ^
ch.cpp:31:16: error: request for member ‘str’ in ‘buf’, which is of non-class type ‘std::ostringstream() {aka std::basic_ostringstream<char>()}’
     return buf.str();
```

I've looked this up in the C++ library reference:
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/sstream/ostringstream/

The reference claims that there is a "non-member overload":

```
ostream& operator<< (ostream& os, const char* s);
```

It also claims that "ostringstream" has a public member, "str()" that returns a string that contains a copy of the contents of the stream buffer.

So why these error messages? Do I need another include?

Comment: "ostringstream buf();"  is a function.  "ostringstream buf;"   is an instance.
    ...

Comment: Hmmm... Okay. Unfortunately I was looking at the wrong part of the problem. So I searched for ostringstream, sstream, etc. and didn't find the duplicate. Sigh.

Comment: Well, I figured out how that problem arose. In a previous compilation I had been getting errors about ostringstream being an "incomplete type". So I thought I had to provide a dummy argument list for the constructor, and added the parens.

That caused the ambiguous syntax that gcc interpreted as a declaration.

The real problem was that I had left out #include<sstream>. Not in the reduced sample code I posted, but in the real code, which was longer, had other includes (one of which included _some_ of the STL/C++iostream headers that I needed).

Comment: The answer to this question gave me the clue to finding the real problem. When I took out the parens, the sample code compiled. But my real code didn't. Okay, what's different? I traced back through my header chain and found the problem. So thanks to Douglas Moen and to those who answered "Default constructor with empty brackets"

Btw, ISTM that at least some compilers used to give you a warning if you used empty parens in a function declaration. The preferred form is name(void).

Comment: I've made the same error enough times that I now recognize it, sometimes prior to the compile error.  I hear clang error message might be more informative.  Some days I can even remember the term "most vexing parse".